# How to click/press in cursor mode in Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 on Xbox with Turtle Beach VelocityOne Flightstick on Xbox Series X

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, microsoft-flight-simulator

I discovered that when playing Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 on Xbox Series X, the tech-sensitive pad on the joystick of my [Turtle Beach VelocityOne Flightstick](https://www.turtlebeach.com/pages/velocity-one-flight-stick) activates Cursor Mode. Sliding my finger around the pad moves the targeting cursor on screen.

But how do I press on an item on screen beneath my targeting cursor? I’m looking for the equivalent of clicking a mouse button.

I pressed every button I could find on the Flightstick device, but none of them clicked-pressed/activated the targeted icon or menu or button.